# How do I execute a DOS SET command from C# and have the variable persist after the exe closes?

Tags: c#, set, dos, process.start

I have a C# console executable started within a DOS command process.

I need to be able to execute DOS commands from the C# executable (specifically I need to be able to SET variables) and have the variables persist such that the rest of the DOS process can reference them.

ie:

Start DOS process
 -> C# executes a SET command to set UserVariable
 -> DOS process can ECHO %UserVariable%

Due to performance reasons I cannot write the set command to a dos script. In fact, I cannot have any file I/O at all.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running a C# app from a dos script and wishing to use variables set in the app afterwards from the script, I don't know how to do that for just the context of that script from within C#, the other answers here show you for the machine itself but I appreciate you need something with a less permanent scope.

A meta-programming workaround this could be to:

- Call the C# app from a DOS FOR loop
- From the C# app, output to the console SET commands
- Use the for loop to execute the app output

The calling DOS script would look like this:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A IN ('MyApp.exe') DO ( 
   %%A
)
```

The Console output from MyApp.exe would need to be in the form:

```
SET UserVariable1=UserValue1
SET UserVariable2=UserValue2
```

And then each of the output lines would be executed by the calling FOR loop and the variables would then exist in the context of the calling script.

Comment: This is perfect :) Just what I was after.

Answer (score 4):

SETX persists the environment variables. Check this: [http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc755104(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc755104%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the response. - How would I retrieve the value afterward? The need is this: For the lifespan of a single command window, we need to be able to set dos variables from C# called within that command window to be accessed in the same command window. Ideally these vales should not persist after the window closes.

Comment: I think that using SETX yourvar= will remove it

Comment: It's not the removal that we're worried about. It's retrieving it for use (eg ECHO %SomeVariable%) in DOS code after the C#. At the moment, unless a workable solution can be found, we're going to have to go with having a single file I/O in the process to write a small batch file with the set commands.

Comment: If you call SETX the variable will remain forever until deleted. So after you execute the SETX command you can access the variable from wherever you want with %var%. You open a cmd, execute SETX test="jj", close the cmd, open another cmd, write %test% and you get jj

Comment: Thank you for the clear and helpful response. Yes, this would work, but it would violate the constraints I am working under so I can't use it unfortunatly.

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't with the fact that you are calling SET from within a C# application. Even if you open a windows prompt and call SET to set a user variable, it will not persist through sessions.

> Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with
>   SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.

[Source](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html).

I advise you to set variables directly through .Net, anyway. You can use [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x.aspx) to do this.

Comment: Of course, if you have a good reason to do it from the prompt, @SoMoS post is the way to go. I'm not stealing his answer though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following .NET method instead:

[Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes)

Comment: Unfortunatly, this didn't work. Using: Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MoTest", "We are Sorted..."); in my C# code I was unable to retrieve the value in the DOS script after the C# code.

Comment: What did you pass for the 3rd parameter?

Comment: Oops, didn't notice the overload. Just tried it with Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MoTest", "We are Sorted...", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process); but got the same result. I am leary about using USER or MACHINE as both of those write to the registry.

Comment: Think about it for a second. You're passing in "Process" and wondering why it's not available outside of your process. Yet, you're leEry of "User" and "Machine" because it writes to the registry. Didn't it cross your mind that for it to be available outside of your process, it needs to be written *SOMEWHERE* and registry happens to be it?

Comment: Thank you for correcting my spelling and yes I am aware that it would need to be written somewhere, but was hoping that someone would know of a method to set the value without file I/O and without using the registry. Our system will have a lot of concurrent scripts running so we won't be using the registry to store values which only need to exist for the lifetime of a single script. Thank you again for all your time and effort, but I think we'll be going with a "compromise" of a single file write per script execution and see how that affects performance.

Comment: —1 because I see no reason to be pedant with the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means an answer, but with the nature of the problem this "compromise" is the path we have chosen for the time being.

We'll be using a batch script created by the C# application which will have all the simple set commands needed which will then be executed by the CMD process that invoked the C# application.

Please feel free to add any further ideas and comments as this is not the ideal solution.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, so far as I can tell, this is the "solution" that is available, through at least Windows 7. I've been experimenting with various ways to set and subsequently use environment variables, and the bottom line of my research is that, if you want to use a variable, it must either be set in advance into the USER or MACHINE key, or it must be a local variable, set by script command, then tested further along in the same script.

So far as I am concerned, the third element in that enumeration, Process, is essentially useless. The only way that I can see that it *might* be useful is if a process spawns another process, passing its environment to the child process. That's overkill for most run-of-the-mill administrative scripts.